# Activeadmin and devise in rails 4

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, ruby-2.0

I am using active admin and devise in rails 4. When i am logging out to the active admin user it will automatically logging out to the devise user also.

Any help would be appreciated....
Thanks

Comment: But how do you have your active admin login configured actually?

Comment: First i logs in to the devise user then if the user is admin it will see Admin link when admin clicks on the Admiin link it is redirected to the /admin which is the Activeadmin login page then again he logs in to the active admin account after logging in to the activeadmin account admin get the logout link then after click on the logout it will be logged out from the devise user too.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a custom logout path in your `active_admin.rb` file. Look for the line with  `config.logout_link_path`

Comment: config.logout_link_path = :destroy_admin_user_session_path
 it should destroy the admin_user session but it is destroying the user_session also.....that's the problem.